# Split ranges with different numbers of rows in one sheet into separate sheets based the value of one columns values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split the data from **Sheets("VISIT HISTORY")** into a varying number of worksheets in the same book which are created and allocated standard Excel names (Sheet1, Sheet2......SheetX) where the number of sheets is determined by the number of unique values in a Column Q.  Q is the primary sort column so the data is structured so all unique values are together.

I have created the sub routine below and it only copies the value in cell `Q2` on **VISIT HISTORY** into `A3` on every subsequent sheet.  It almost works in that it does copy data into the right starting field on each sheet but the data is not right and it doesn't seem to copy or write the right range of data.  The data I need is the block of rows where the Q is the same including columns A through P.

When I step through the debug mode it appears as though the variables `LR`, `Rw` and `Rw2` have the right values stored to make the `Range("A & Rw2:P & Rw").Select` command select the right data but it doesn't produce the results I would expect.

I suspect this is where the problem is.  Any advice would be appreciated

```
Sub CutAndPasteBlocksOfDataBetweenSheets()
Dim LR As Long, Rw As Long, Rw2 As Long
LR = Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'last row with data
Rw2 = 2
For Rw = 2 To LR Step 1                    'from the top down, compare
On Error Resume Next
If Range("Q" & Rw).Value <> Range("Q" & Rw + 1).Value Then _
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheet1.Select
Range("A & Rw2:P & Rw").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet" & Sheets.Count - 1).Select
Range("A3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Paste    
Sheets("VISIT HISTORY").Select
If Range("Q" & Rw).Value <> Range("Q" & Rw + 1).Value Then _
Rw2 = Rw + 1    
Next Rw
End Sub
```

The comment pointed me in the right direction - thanks.  For anyone who may be interested the working code looked like this:

```
Sub CutAndPasteBlocksOfDataBetweenSheets()
Dim LR As Long, Rw As Long, Rw2 As Long
'Cut and Paste data into individual sheets
LR = Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'last row with data
Rw2 = 1
For Rw = 1 To LR Step 1                    'from the top down, compare

If Range("Q" & Rw).Value <> Range("Q" & Rw + 1).Value Then _
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Range("A" & Rw2 & ":P" & Rw + 1).Copy
Sheets("Sheet" & Sheets.Count - 1).Select
Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("VISIT HISTORY").Select
If Range("Q" & Rw).Value <> Range("Q" & Rw + 1).Value Then _
Rw2 = Rw + 1

Next Rw
```

Comment: There are many things 1) Remove `On Error Resume Next` 2) You will see the code fails on `Range("A & Rw2:P & Rw").Select` Because `"A & Rw2:P & Rw"` is a string. I guess you were trying this? `Range("A" & Rw2 & ":P" & Rw)` 3) Avoid `.SELECT`. Directly perform the relevant operation.

Comment: FYI, I would get rid of your Copy/Paste in VBA, especially if you're just getting values. Instead, try `Range("A3:P" & Rw + 4).value = Range("A" & Rw2 & ":P" & Rw + 1).value '+4 for your original +1 offset added to the starting row of 3`